# What is the Naming Convention of sub-packages of the Android Studio Projects? (MAD)

Tags: android, package-name

I have been around for a short time and has always been questioning about the best practices for naming sub packages for an android project.

Suppose I have the sub packages to be named from two or more words. What will be the best **industry standard practice** to name it?

Should I use like,

```
For "User Auth":

userauth or,
userAuth or,
user_auth or,
user-Auth ?

For "Now Playing":

nowplaying
now_playing
now-playing
nowPlaying


For "Feature Chart Flow":

featurechartflow
feature_chart_flow
feature-chart-flow
featureChartFlow
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please review the rules and guidelines before posting.  In particular, questions soliciting opinions such as on "best practices" are considering off topic.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic

Comment: Are naming conventions that are provided in the official documentation opinion-based? Even though the questioner uses the term "best practice", I am not sure if this question actually is opinion-based. There are many questions regarding naming conventions on stackoverflow, but it seems these kind of questions are barely getting closed: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=naming+conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [naming conventions for Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules) suggest the following:

> Names of packages are always lowercase and do not use underscores (`org.example.project`). Using multi-word names is generally discouraged, but if you do need to use multiple words, you can either just concatenate them together or use the camel case (`org.example.myProject`).

So in your case, when your package name can't be reduced to a single word, use concatenation or camelCase:

```
userAuth
userauth
nowPlaying
nowplaying
featureChartFlow
featurechartflow
```

You should however try to only use a single word as package name. You could for example use `auth` instead of `userAuth`. 
 You can also consider to restructure your application and split the packages:

```
auth
├── user
│   ├── ComposableA.kt
│   └── ComposableB.kt
├── admin
│   ├── ComposableX.kt
│   ├── ComposableY.kt
│   └── ComposableZ.kt
```